# How to prove statement is wrong

Tags: coq

Trying to prove the following lemma I got stuck. Usully theorems about lists are proven using induction, but I don't know where to move next.
I am trying to prove a statement, which is wrong. Therefore trying to prove it false. Here is lemma statement.Plz guide me in closing this sub-lemma.

```
Theorem list_length :
  forall (l:list nat),
    (length l =? 0) = false ->
    (length l - length l =? 0) = false.
Proof.
  intros. induction (length l).
  simpl in *. apply H. simpl. 
  rewrite IHn0. auto.  simpl in H.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217573/discussion-on-question-by-rosi-javi-how-to-prove-statement-is-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that forall (l:list nat),
(length l =? 0) = false ->
(length l - length l =? 0) = false is unprovable if you notice the case when the length of the list is 0, is actually true but to others cases is not.

If you're trying to prove the statement but it's wrong, so you just have to negate.

```
Theorem list_length :
  forall (l:list nat),
    ~ (length l - length l =? 0) = false.
   intros.
   intro H.
   (*now, do your magic here *)
```

By now, the proof is very trivial.
I will let you finish this proof now.

Answer (score 1):

As you rightly noticed, the hypothesis I named `abs` in my version of the script is false and you should be able to derive anything from this.  The only
difficulty is to make Coq see it.
You need to a theorem to explain that `(something - something)` is always `0`.  I give you the search command for this.  Then, you have
to know that Coq will finish the proof using computation.  Here, `0 =? 0` computes to `true`.  Then `abs` modulo computation is `true = false`.
The tactic `discriminate` has been designed specifically to finish proofs in this case.

```
Search (?x - ?x).

Theorem index_val_0:
  forall (l:list nat), (length l =? 0) = false ->
    (length l - length l=?0)=false-> 
    (index_value(length l - length l-1) l =? 0) = true.
Proof.
intros l lnnil abs.
Fail discriminate.
rewrite Nat.sub_diag in abs.
discriminate.
Qed.
```